# Varying (known) number of outputs in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a Snakemake rule that works on a data archive and essentially unpacks the data in it. The archives contain a varying number of files that I know before my rule starts, so I would like to exploit this and do something like

```
rule unpack:
    input: '{id}.archive'
    output: 
        lambda wildcards: ARCHIVE_CONTENTS[wildcards.id]
```

but I can't use functions in `output`, and for good reason. However, I can't come up with a good replacement. The rule is very expensive to run, so I cannot do

```
rule unpack:
    input: '{id}.archive'
    output: '{id}/{outfile}'
```

and run the rule several times for each archive. Another alternative could be

```
rule unpack:
    input: '{id}.archive'
    output: '{id}/{outfile}'
    run:
        if os.path.isfile(output[0]):
            return
        ...
```

but I am afraid that would introduce a race condition.

Is marking the rule output with `dynamic` really the only option? I would be fine with auto-generating a separate rule for every archive, but I haven't found a way to do so.

Comment: What do the archive contents look like? How are they used downstream?

Comment: They are containing some raw products that are getting processed further down the chain. Those processed files are the final outputs. This rule occurs approximately in the middle of a longer chain.

Comment: But Snakemake is for processing structured data. If the archives all contain files that are different, using Snakemake makes little sense.

Comment: Who says it's not structured? There is a structure, and I know it before processing. It may be too complicated for Snakemake, though, and that would be unfortunate. For the sake of argument you can assume that each archive stands for a date, and each file in it is a single measurement. I also happen to have a list of all available measurements per date. It feels like this is a simple enough setup that Snakemake should be able to handle it, especially since everything is perfectly deterministic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, it becomes handy that Snakemake is an extension of plain Python. You can generate a separate rule for each archive:

```
for id, contents in ARCHIVE_CONTENTS.items():
    rule:
        input: 
            '{id}.tar.gz'.format(id=id)
        output: 
            expand('{id}/{outfile}', outfile=contents)
        shell:
            'tar -C {wildcards.id} -xf {input}'
```

Depending on what kind of archive this is, you could also have a single rule that just extracts the desired file, e.g.:

```
rule unpack:
    input:
        '{id}.tar.gz'
    output:
        '{id}/{outfile}'
    shell:
        'tar -C {wildcards.id} -xf {input} {wildcards.outfile}'
```

Comment: Awesome, your first suggestion was exactly what I was looking for! What about the name of the rule? Can I give it a placeholder name, or one that is unique for each input?

Comment: @Dion Rules do not need to have a name. I don't know what happens when the loop declares rules with the same name. I'm curious to know how one could dynamically generate rule name.

Comment: Sure, but it would be nicer to have something more descriptive than `9`. Setting a constant name crashes (rule already exists).